# FlatFileParseException.getLineNumber() giving incorrect line numbers of erroneous records

Tags: spring-batch

I have set up a spring batch job to read from a **.csv file** and dump the entire data into DB. Since .csv is a flat file, obvious choice was framework's own flat file reader `org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader`

I also wrote a listener which listens for any error while reading the file and gets the faulty input as well as line number on which exception occurred during parsing.

Here is the code for listener --

```
@Override
public void onReadError(Exception e){

if (e instanceof FlatFileParseException){

FlatFileParseException ffpe = (FlatFileParseException)e;
errorMessage.append("Could not process line number --"+ffpe.getLineNumber());
errorMessager.append("Faulty Input --"+ffpe.getInput());
logger.error(errorMessage.toString());
}
```

Here is my batch job config ---

```
<batch:job id="myjob">
 <batch:step id="validateFile" next="nextStep">
  <batch:tasklet ref="validateFileTasklet" />
 </batch:step>

 <batch:step id="nextStep">
  <batch:tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor" throttle-limit="5">
   <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="mysqlItemWriter" commit-interval="5" skip-limit="5">
    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
     <batch:include   class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileParseException" />
     </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
    <batch:listeners>
      <batch:listener>
        <bean class="org.organizationname.productname.batch.listener.FlatFileParseExceptionListener" />
      </batch:listener>
    </batch:listeners>
  </batch:chunk>
 </batch:tasklet>
 </batch:job>
```

The validator, reader and writer are all well defined and working correctly.

`TaskExecutor` is the `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`.

Then I tamper my sample .csv file to partially delete values from records in order to produce the exception. As expected, the exceptions occurs. Listener fires but it gives incorrect line numbers. Though it gives right faulty input every time.

Line numbers also vary if I run it repeatedly. For instance, I tampered line number 3 and 11 of my .csv sample file but listener gave me line number 6 and line number 12 as records where exception occurred. It also gave me line number 5 and 11 sometimes for the same tampered records.

Any ideas as to why would this happen??

Comment: Could you give your flat file and track trace? And do you have any line as comments?

Comment: @NghiaDo Thanks for the reply. No I do not have any lines as comments. I just trimmed a field's value out of all fields in .csv for a couple of records. Sorry that I cannot provide Stack trace as of now.

Comment: Can you reproduce issue without `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`?

Comment: @SabirKhan Will give it a try. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do parallel reading without synchronizing your writer. It is very likely, not  to say almost certain, that another thread has already updated the `linecounter` of your `FlatFileItemReader` when the first thread creates the `Exception`.

[Use this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SynchronizedItemStreamReader.html) in order to wrap your reader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But reading the documentation of SynchronizedItemStreamReader I came across that using it will render a job not restartable. So is there another way out?

Comment: that is correct. As soon as you want to process your items in parallel, you loose restartability for this step. The problem is, that the read-order of the chunks doesn't have to be the same when the chunks are written. you would need to implement your own logic how to handle that. But I don't think that you wanna do this. how many entries do you need to read and write? If you just want to improve performance, setting your commitsize to 10000 or 20000 could and using a single threaded step could improve your performance significantly, if you generally expect no skips.

Comment: As you guessed it the order is not important. Thanks for the explanation. I think I need to wrap my reader as you suggested or remove the 'SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor' in order to see if line numbers are still incorrect.